# Is there a pronunciation exercise for ㄹ. (I am a French native speaker)

Tags: pronunciation

I understand the general pronunciation rules for the consonant ㄹ but my problem is that I'm not able to pronounce the Korean ㄹ when it should be between the American R and L.

I am a native French speaker so I roll my R from my throat like it should be when we pronounce R in French but I'm not able to pronounce the Korean R from the tongue. It seems that the specific muscle of my tongue for that has never been activated and is sleeping.

Is there any pronunciation exercises I can do for that?

It's the same "R" from Bahasa Indonesia, it's a "R" from the tongue and not from the throat like in French.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Well, Korean ㄹ is not the same as the Indonesian R, which is trilled. Korean ㄹ is never trilled. The point of articulation (your alveolar ridge) is similar, though. If you’re familiar with American English, try the flap T sound (e.g. “Bu**tt**er”).

Comment: It seems to work, at least when I put my hand on my throat and I try to pronounce 여름 with the same T sound for the ㄹ from the American English word “Butter”, I don't feel my throat buzzing.

Comment: Good. From the alveolar ridge, where /t/ is articulated, push the tip of your tongue a tiny little bit (a few millimeters) towards the teeth. That’s the ㄹ sound.